# Averaging Multiple Models Word2vec Gensim

Tags: python, python-2.7, gensim, word2vec

I have trained few million words in `Word2Vec` of `Gensim` of Python. I want to update this trained model with new data. 
But from your previous posts and other sources around the web I came to know this is not possible.
So I am trying to create multiple models and dump them. Now I want to merge the models I am dumping. I want to use these dumped results. I got a previous post [Merging pretrained models in Word2Vec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482669/merging-pretrained-models-in-word2vec)
but I am not getting how to do it. I came to know there is a library named deepdist, I am trying to see some experiments around:

```
model = word2vec.Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('/tmp/vectors.bin', binary=True)
```

1. Is there a possible solution?
2. If any, one may kindly suggest how to do it?

I am using Python2.7 on Windows 7 Professional.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you pointed to does NOT suggest merging the models as a solution. Actually, they are suggesting you to use the different models that you have separately. Cast a prediction with each of the models and then combine the answers. There are several approaches to combine the output. In your case you mention you have several models, so you can ignore the part of that answer where they suggest to break your training data in 2 in order to actually have 3 models casting predictions. You can use a majority voting policy as long as you have more than 2 predictions.

Comment: He said "Divide your data set into 2 equal size data set, then train both of them" I can also think like that, with my newdata and olddata, if I say newdata=data_of_size1, and olddata=data_of_size2, where size1=size2. If I merge my model of newdata and model of olddata my problem gets solved. Am I wrong if I say it? But how to do it?

Comment: Often times models use aggregated data that cannot be directly merged. Regardless is the size of the data, is the models can work on their own, just use them separately and merge the predictions instead.